# ionic build android error

Tags: android, cordova, windows-7-x64, ionic-framework

I'm very new to the ionic framework,how ever I've cordova up and running in the windows 7 system but now  I'm trying to build an android app with ionic framework and i followed the following steps

```
>npm install -g cordova
>npm install -g ionic
>ionic start resistance blank
>cd resistance
>ionic platform add android
```

Till here I'm doing good but when I run the command

```
>ionic build android
```

i get the following error

```
    C:\Users\vishwant\resistance>ionic build android
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\Users\vishwant\resistance\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js C:\Users\vishwant\resis
tance
add to body class: platform-android
Running command: C:\Users\vishwant\resistance\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat

C:\Users\vishwant\resistance\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\tools\tools\lib\build.template'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:432:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:289:15)
    at C:\Users\vishwant\resistance\platforms\android\cordova\lib\build.js:120:40
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\vishwant\resistance\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:798:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\vishwant\resistance\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:827:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\vishwant\resistance\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:760:13)
    at C:\Users\vishwant\resistance\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:574:44
    at flush (C:\Users\vishwant\resistance\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
Error: C:\Users\vishwant\resistance\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\vishwant\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```

I notice that the path is incorrect , but in the path variable I've set up correctly i.e till tools.

> Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory
>   'C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\tools\tools\lib\build.template'

Firstly,I don't understand why it's attaching one more tools\ and searching for the build.template
Secondly, If i manual create that extra tools\ folder inside the tools\ (which i want to avoid) then this above error is gone but i will be shown

```
C:\Users\vishwant\resistance>ionic build android
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\Users\vishwant\resistance\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js C:\Users\vishwant\resis
tance
add to body class: platform-android
Running command: C:\Users\vishwant\resistance\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat
[Error: Please install Android target "android-19".
Hint: Run "android" from your command-line to open the SDK manager.]
Error: C:\Users\vishwant\resistance\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\vishwant\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```

Since I've already installed android sdks and the targets 4.4W which is working fine for the cordova projects, I don't understand why it's failing for the ionic framework.

Please correct me If I'm missing out something.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess it's because you set ANDROID_HOME to the wrong path.

ANDROID_HOME must be set to the root of the android SDK, not to tools folder:

```
SET ANDROID_HOME=C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk
```

But the tools folder must be in the path.

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools
```

(of course use windows settings to set env vars, don't do it in cmd, that was just to explain more clearly)

Answer (score 3):

For Mac OSX users: you can modify your bashprofile

```
~ nano .bash_profile
```

Then add the following lines to the file and save it

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/<path_to_your_androidsdk>/
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Reboot your system and run a build

```
ionic build android
```

Took me some time to figure that out, hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Earlier it was

```
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/bin
```

Now it's

```
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your android sdk path is set correctly.

Here is the way to set using command prompt then restart it:

```
SET ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk

SET PATH=%PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools
```

or you can set it from system setting page.