# "Ionic build android" error

Tags: java, android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm new to Ionic and trying to install it using [this tutorial](http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/installation.html).

Now everything works, I'm able to create a project and add a platform but when I try to run the command "ionic build android" I get this error:

[image]

I ran the `ant debug` command but it doesn't work.

I don't have a clue on how to solve this. I tried to reinstall everything, double checked my environment variables and removed and added the android platform again, but nothing works.

I also tried some of the other solutions posted here in some related topics but it seems my error here is still a little bit different.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it's because you set ANDROID_HOME to the wrong path.

ANDROID_HOME must be set to the root of the android SDK, not to tools folder:

```
SET ANDROID_HOME=C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk
```

But the tools folder must be in the path.

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools
```

(use windows settings to set env vars, don't do it in cmd, that was just to explain more clearly)

[Answer Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27120950/ionic-build-android-error?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: This cured it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just follow this video, you have to set your path correctly.

http://learn.ionicframework.com/videos/windows-android/

1: Download and Install Java then open your system environment variables, and add to or create a new user variable called PATH with the full path to the bin folder of the new Java SDK installation.

2: Download Apache Ant then add the full path to the bin/ folder to the end of your PATH environment variable.

3: Add Android to PATH :Open up your environment variables setting and add the full path to both the adt-bundle/sdk/platform-tools/ folder and the adt-bundle/sdk/tools/ folder to the end of your PATH variable:

4.Install nodeJs and now you can do

```
 npm install -g cordova ionic
```