# error while running ionic build android

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I wanted to run my app on my phone but when i run the command I get an error. My Android_Home="$HOME\Android\Sdk" but but in the Ionic builing shows that it is Andorid_Home="usr\lib\android-sdk"

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: okey .. 
so my ANDROID_HOME="home\Safouene\SDK" 
but when i run " ionic cordova run android " 
it says that my ANDROID_HOME="usr/lib/android-sdk" 
and that i have to accept a licence there

Comment: I still don't understand what your problem is. Perhaps this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27122345/3252438) could help you.